# Cumulative Total in Power BI- YTD Budget

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop

Im working in POWERBI and trying to calculate an YTD Budget Measures for the rolling total of the previous month.

For YTD Budget of 2018 = sum of monthly expenses from Jun to Aug.

My Measure:

YTD Budget = 
VAR
MaxPeriod = CALCULATE(MAX('DATA'[PERIOD]),'DATA'[SCENARIO] = "Actual")
RETURN
CALCULATE(sum('DATA'[AMOUNT]),'DATA'[SCENARIO] = "Budget", 'DATA'[PERIOD] <= MaxPeriod)

How can I calculate the accumulative month total by YTD Budget? Just, Jun to Aug.

[image: Data]

Expected Outcome:

Department Country  Class   Scenario    Month   Fiscal Year  Expenses
HR          Chile       Salary    Actual    Jun      FY-2018      8837
HR          Chile       Salary    Actual    Jul      FY-2018      6288
HR          Chile       Salary    Actual    Aug      FY-2018      6096

HR          Colombia    Salary    Actual    Jun      FY-2018      6187
HR          Colombia    Salary    Actual    Jul      FY-2018      6547
HR          Colombia    Salary    Actual    Aug      FY-2018      7613

HR          Chile      Salary     Budget    Jun       FY-2018     6062
HR          Chile      Salary     Budget    Jul       FY-2018     7491
HR          Chile      Salary     Budget    Aug       FY-2018     6689

HR          Colombia    Salary    Budget    Jun       FY-2018     7191
HR          Colombia    Salary    Budget    Jul       FY-2018     8466
HR          Colombia    Salary    Budget    Aug       FY-2018     6976

YTD- Actual: 41,568.00
YTD- Budget: 42,875.00

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please post your starting data as text rather than an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have download your data and applied this measure:

```
YTD Budget = CALCULATE(sum('Data'[Expenses]);AND(Data[Period]>=IF(MONTH(Today())>=6;MONTH(Today())-5;MONTH(Today())+3)-4;Data[Period]<=IF(MONTH(Today())>=6;MONTH(Today())-5;MONTH(Today())+3)-1);Data[Scenario]="Budget";ALLEXCEPT(DATA;Data[Scenario]))

YTD Actual = CALCULATE(sum('Data'[Expenses]);AND(Data[Period]>=IF(MONTH(Today())>=6;MONTH(Today())-5;MONTH(Today())+3)-4;Data[Period]<=IF(MONTH(Today())>=6;MONTH(Today())-5;MONTH(Today())+3)-1);Data[Scenario]="Actual";ALLEXCEPT(DATA;Data[Scenario]))
```

Think I got the results you want for the period between June and August

Or without the filter Data[Scenario]="Actual" or Data[Scenario]="Budget" to have the separate results by each of this records

[image: Table in PowerBI]

If is not this that you look please tell me!

Comment: Thank you. What about next month? I need to change the [Period]<=3) measure every time? Example  [Period]<=4) Sept, so on.

Comment: That´s a little bit more complex that I was thinking but I replace in the formula the 3 of Data[Period] for IF(MONTH(Today())>6;MONTH(Today())-5;MONTH(Today())+3)-1. This will get the month of Aug (the previous month). And an equivalent formula for Jun. This help for your solution?

Comment: It’s not working. Can you verify my measure with the IF statement? YTD Budget = CALCULATE(sum('CONSOLIDATED EXPENSES'[AMOUNT]),'CONSOLIDATED EXPENSES'[PERIOD]>=1,  IF(MONTH(Today())>6;MONTH(Today())-5;MONTH(Today())+3)-1 'CONSOLIDATED EXPENSES'[SCENARIO]="Budget",ALLEXCEPT('CONSOLIDATED EXPENSES','CONSOLIDATED EXPENSES'[SCENARIO]))

Comment: Expenses and your AMOUNT are the same column, right? Also your parentises appear to be different then in my solution. You have some error or different result?

Comment: Nevermind!! Its working. Thank you for all your help.